# How do I parse out the following HTML in python beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Assume the following is a subset of the HTML document... note there are multiple tables that repeat, though the `<a name="1">` may be "2", "3" , "4", etc. with different text for each table.

```
<table align="center" width="550">
<tr>
<td valign="top" width="300"><b>Product:</b></img></td>
<td>
<a name="1"></a>1) Text Editor
<p>An application for the editing of text files.</p>
<br>
<b>Application Name: Notepad</b>
<br>            
<b>Type: Writing</b>
<br><br></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to find an "a" tag that equals a particular "#" (in this case, 1)
and be able to somehow get the text of: "1) Text Editor".

I know if I beautifulsouped the whole document I can use something like `findAll("table")` to give me all the tables, but I do not know how I can possibly get to that value. I may be able to do something like `findAll("a")`, but how would I specify the "name" to be equal to (1 in this case)? Even if I could do that, I wouldnt be able to get to the "1) Text Editor" since that "a" tag is empty.. and I also couldnt get to things like the "`<b>Application Name: Notepad</b>`" part.

What is the best solution with a combination of python/beautifulsoup, or if there is some better way to get that "1) Text Editor" and "Application Name" and "Type" parts of the table out based on the fact that there is a `<a name="1"></a>` that precedes it? Sample syntax would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify attributes with `findAll` ...

```
>>> a = soup.findAll("a", attrs={"name": "1"})[0]
```

... and then get the next node ...

```
>>> a.next
u'1) Text Editor\n'
```

... and the next `<b>` element ...

```
>>> a.findNext("b")
<b>Application Name: Notepad</b>
```

... and so on.

By the way, the `attrs` argument is only necessary because `name` is a special argument to `findAll()`. If it had been some other attribute, you could have used e.g.

```
>>> a = soup.findAll("a", href="whatever")
```

Comment: Note one of the parts I want to extract is not wrapped in any tag: the "1) Text Editor" part.

Comment: Once you've found the `<a>` element, the next node is the text you're looking for. See the bit about `a.next` :-)

Comment: ... in other words, a node is not the same thing as an element, and it can be just some text.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can easily pass in a dictionary of `attrs` to match against.  This looks like it includes `name` attribute.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#arg-attrs

```
soup.findAll(attrs={'name' : '1'})
```

If you haven't checked it out the documentation provides plenty of really great examples on how to find elements in HTML doc.

Comment: That gives me the following: <a name="1"></a>, but how do I get to its parent element so that I can get to the other properties I wanted to get to? (i.e. the 1) TextEditor, Application Name, etc.) or is there some better way for me to extract out those? The issue is the contents of what i want to get to are not wrapped around within that "a" tag, but the parent element outside that a tag.